# Make mulitple divs line up next to each other inside parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched the many similar questions like this, but none of the solutions are working. It should also be noted that **I am using twitter bootstrap**. I want a bunch of divs to span the entire length of the parent div at the bottom of it. I have tried putting them inside a div that text-align:center and then using float-left inside the gridPics class, and using display: inline-block, text-align :left and nothing seems to do it. The two in the example below are in the exact same spot, and I want them side by side. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8 offset2 articleContent">
        <!-- These are the divs to span across, when it works there would be more than two -->
        <div class="gridPics"></div>
        <div class="gridPics"></div>
        <!-- They will also go over this image -->
        <img id="sidePic" src="img/about/aboutHeader_Mid1.png" alt="about">
    </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .gridPics{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 10%;
   height: 20%;
   background: #0000b3;
   bottom: 0;
   float: left;
 }


 .articleContent{
   position: relative;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
  }

 #sidePic{
   position: relative;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

Here is where I am doing this, the blue divs would be pics (akin to thumbnails) that can be clicked. I want them to go all the way across:

/ScreenShot2013-01-09at85450PM_zps550e8e4a.png[/IMG][image: Where I am trying to achieve this]

Comment: any illustration?screenshot sample of what you want to achieve?or jsfiddle it?

Comment: @Vainglory07 I posted where I am trying to accomplish it at.

Comment: so you want to tile the blue thumbnails horizontally?

Comment: @Vainglory07 Yea,my plan is to make two rows of them that go horizontally across that div, right on top of each other.

Comment: have you tried yo use float:left; for each thumbnails?

Comment: @Vainglory07Yea, I currently have that in the CSS above in class ".gridPics". Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pureux/Er9eG/

You need a container for your gridPics and have it be absolute positioned (instead of the gridPics) at the bottom. Then float the gridPics inside of the container.

```
.picContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.gridPics {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   margin-right: 4px;
   margin-top: 4px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do:[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/BH4cA/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span8 offset2 articleContent">
      <div class="gridPics"></div>
      <div class="gridPics"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <img id="sidePic" src="img/about/aboutHeader_Mid1.png" alt="about">
  </div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gridPics{
    width: 10%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000b3;
    float: left;
    border:solid #FFF 1px;
 }
 .articleContent{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
 }

 #sidePic{
    z-index: -1;
 }
```

Comment: @PerfectDark Yes that's the right idea, but to go over the image as Perfect Dark mentioned.